# Spring boot write predicate to retrieve user from given role list

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, predicate

I am trying to create a predicate to retrieve users having certain Role list (Role is a separate Table )
I have created predicate for other fields in User entity only unable to create the proper criteria for the above mentioned scenario.
below are the 2 entity classes

**User:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Data
public class User implements Serializable {
    public User() {
    }

    public User(User user) {
        this.username = user.getUsername();
        this.password = user.getPassword();
        this.email = user.getEmail();
        this.fullName = user.getFullName();
        this.address = user.getAddress();
        this.contactNo = user.getContactNo();
        this.enabled = user.isEnabled();
        this.accountNonExpired = user.isAccountNonExpired();
        this.credentialsNonExpired = user.isCredentialsNonExpired();
        this.accountNonLocked = user.isAccountNonLocked();
        this.roles = user.getRoles();
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "fullName")
    private String fullName;
    @Column(name = "contactNo")
    private String contactNo;
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "enabled")
    private boolean enabled;
    @Column(name = "accountNonExpired")
    private boolean accountNonExpired;
    @Column(name = "credentialsNonExpired")
    private boolean credentialsNonExpired;
    @Column(name = "accountNonLocked")
    private boolean accountNonLocked;


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "role_user", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    private List<Role> roles;
}
```

**Role**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
@Data
public class Role implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "permission_role", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "permission_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    private List<Permission> permissions;


}
```

I have to use predicates No other option.
guide  me how to write a predicate to get users who are having given Role list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to Java 8 Predicate class:

```
Predicate<User> userPredicate = user -> user.getRoles().equals(roleListArg);
```

If you want a more complex predicate:

```
Predicate<User> userPredicate = user -> { 
     ... your code here
};
```

Take care while comparing List objects like that. Should be better to check if the user has certains roles (user.getRoles().contains(role))

If you refer to JPA Specification:

```
public Specification<User> getUserByRoles(List<Role> roles) {
   return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) => {
      Join<Role, User> join = root.join("role");
      //Return the condition you want to build, this is an example to get by role id
      return criteriaBuilder.in(join.get(id), roles.get(0).getId());
   }
}
```

Comment: I Use  below  ` CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<User> cq = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(User.class);

        Root<User> userRoot = cq.from(User.class);
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.like(userRoot.get("fullName"), "%"+fullName+"%")));
      Predicate[] predArray = new Predicate[predicates.size()];
        predicates.toArray(predArray);

        cq.where(predArray);
        TypedQuery<User> query = em.createQuery(cq);
`

Comment: Don't use the criteriaBuilder.and when adding elements to the list
Add them directly and in the "cq.where" use "cq.where(criteriaBuilder.and(predArray));
You can use the Join an criteriaBuilder as in the example i posted above. Is the same but with lambdas, so you can use a similar code.
Just remember that the "join" variable will access properties in the Role class while the "root" variable will access properties in User class